# How to concat index in 2 dataframe only using one index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset `df1[0]`

```
        Column1    Column2    Column3
0
1
2
```

My next dataset `df2[0]`

```
        Column4    Column5    Column6
203A
206B
207A
```

`frames_all_1 = pd.concat(df1[0], df2[0], axis=1)`

and what I did is

`df1[0].index = df2[0].index`

And the error message

`NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'`

Before that, I try this

`pd.concat([df1[0], df2[0]], axis=1)`

and the result

```
        Column1    Column2    Column3   Column4    Column5    Column6
0                                           NaN        NaN         NaN
1                                           NaN        NaN         NaN
2                                           NaN        NaN         NaN
203A    NaN        NaN         NaN
206B    NaN        NaN         NaN
207A    NaN        NaN         NaN
```

My Expected output

```
        Column1    Column2    Column3   Column4    Column5    Column6
203A    
206B    
207A
```

Comment: the length of both df's are same?

Comment: Yes, it just numerical and categorical variable, nut actullay they tahve different amount of columns

Comment: then do `df2=df2.reset_index()` after that `df1[df2.columns]=df2` finally `df1=df1.set_index('index')`

Comment: I can't reset index df2, it is the customer ID that need to be scored

Comment: well you can also set that back to index in that case....i.e `df2=df2.set_index('index')`

Comment: pd.concat([df1, df2.reset_index()], axis=1).set_index('index')

Comment: @Nk03 KeyError: "None of ['index'] are in the columns"

Comment: @AnuragDabas Please edit your answer, I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is `rename` index values by dictionary before `concat`:

```
d = dict(zip(df1[0].index, df2[0].index))
print (d)

pd.concat([df1[0].rename(d), df2[0]], axis=1)
```

---

Error means there is in list `df1` or `df2` instead `DataFrame` some `None` object, so all solutions should failed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from initial phase:

**First way:**

```
result=pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1).dropna(subset=['Column4'])
result.loc[:,df1.columns]=df1.values
```

**Second Way:**

```
result=pd.concat([df1, df2.reset_index()], axis=1).set_index('index')
```

**Third Way:**

```
result=df1.copy()
df2=df2.reset_index()
result[df2.columns]=df2
result=result.set_index('index')
df2=df2.set_index('index')
```

Now If you print `result` you will get your desired output

Comment: my expected output has nothing to do with drop columns, its about index

Comment: updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
frames_all_1 = pd.concat(df1[0], df2[0], axis=1)
```

try to reset index first and then concat

Comment: I still need the index from df2[0]

Comment: Just try the code and its error message  `NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'
`

Comment: if you need index of df2 skip this line `df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` , first declare df1 and df2 as some data frames to it to remove above error